# Light Bow Gun Special Ammo Types

Tags: monster-hunter-world

Without spoiling any of the game, can anyone tell me if there are other special ammo types for the Light Bow Gun, other than the mine things you can place which trigger when you fire through them? 
The Heavy Bow Gun has at least two special types that I know of (Wyvernsnipe and the rapid fire mode), but I've only seen one for the LBG

(I'm afraid I don't have the game on me while writing this so I can't check the name of the ammo type. Something along the lines of Wyvern____)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the only special ammo type currently available for LBG is **Wyvernblast** which are the mines.

The only two special ammo types for HBG are **Wyvernsnipe**, which is the long piercing shot that explodes; and **Wyvernheart**, which is the machine gun type ammo.

I have access to the entire weapon tree. The metal tree of HBG is entirely Wyvernheart, the bone tree is entirely Wyvernsnipe. The LBG has Wyvernblast for the entire metal *and* bone trees.